# LXPanel: Show active window title & close/min-max/restore buttons

Tags: lubuntu, panel, lxde, titlebar, lxpanel

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** I have now found out that these plug-ins are possible, but do not exist. I submitted a request on the LXDE SourceForge page [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/lxde/feature-requests/239/). They responded, saying they like the idea, but the implementation will take some time due to insufficient man-power.

**IN SHORT:** I am trying to find a way of mimicking the Unity 2D panel (global menu NOT NEEDED. Many people said that OpenBox can't handle global menus, that I should use another window manager, BUT I DON'T WANT/NEED THE GLOBAL MENU. Thanks. Sorry for caps, needed to empathize that).

**IN LONG:** I have quite an old notebook. I tried installing Ubuntu (12.04 Wubi), that was too slow for me, but my friend recommended Lubuntu, which I tried installing as a desktop environment by `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`. I now use it all the time, but I miss one thing - the Unity panel which served as a top bar for the maximized windows. I'm not on a very large screen, so space is valuable.

I have quite a lot of indicators, so when I used the default bar, it was always full to the brim, with no space left for the window list.

So I tried using the `unity-2d-panel`, but it has it's minuses in LXDE. It's not very lightweight, it's close/min-max/restore buttons are ugly because of a bug when using non-native themes (non-Ambiance or Radiance themes), and I can't change much about it (the theme, position, items, transparency), as I am used to in LXPanel (for info I use it as the bottom panel along with the unity panel which is on the top). Also, the menu doesn't always disappear in applications, so the global menu becomes useless.

**UPDATE:** `unity-2d-panel` also crashes a lot, and isn't omni-present (present on all workspaces).

So I want to go back to LXPanel, but I want to keep the integrated window bar.

I tried googling, and I found [this](https://github.com/xkollar/lxpanel-window-title), but I don't know how to use it, whether to use it, and it still lacks the buttons mentioned earlier.
**UPDATE:** Googling now finds this question on number 1.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
The close/min-max/restore buttons             Indicators applet
[——]                                             [————————]
___________________________________________________________
x↓↑  An Example Window Title                     Indicators
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
     [—————————————————————]
     The active window Title
```

The buttons with the title should (optimally) only show when the window is maximized. Is there any way to do this? I don't need the global menu.

Thanks. This was my first question, so feel free to correct me if I messed anything up or posted a duplicate :)

**PS:** This question is more than a week here, and lacks an answer, so please, if you want an answer too, upvote the question. The question will be more visible (higher chance of answering), and also it may give me the opportunity to give a bounty on this question.

**Note: This should be possible.** The built-in "Task Bar (Window List)" plug-in in LXPanel actually has most of the functions needed (that is showing the window title, maximizing, minimizing, restoring closing the window, **but I am not sure if it can get the active window**).
SO, this combined with `maximus` (which I already use combined with `unity-2d-panel`), **would be technically possible.**